# Where to put my.ini file for 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, windows

I have copied the `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini` to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini` and changed some settings including setting `table_definition_cache=400`.  When I log into the database and look at the `table_definition_cache` value I get the following:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%table_definition_cache%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| table_definition_cache | 1400  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Where do I need to put my `my.ini` file such that the database loads it on startup?

Comment: Amazing...I solved my problem using your question.

Answer (score 2):

The folder `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` is the correct location for `my.ini`.

There are two possible reasons 1400 shows up as [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache).

## REASON #1

You did not restart mysql.

Login to Windows DOS command line as Administrator and run

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

Value should be in place afterwards.

## REASON #2

The default value for [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache) is `-1 (autosized)`. That makes mysqld figure out a fair value for [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache), given your OS configuration.

## CAVEAT

Make sure you place

```
table_definition_cache = 400
```

under the `[mysqld]` group header before you restart mysql

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

I dug a little further and learned why 1400 comes up for [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache)

According to the Documentation for [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache)

> The default value is based on the following formula, capped to a limit of 2000:
>
> ```
> 400 + (table_open_cache / 2)
> ```

The [default value for table_open_cache is 2000](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache)

Applying the formula

```
400 + (table_open_cache / 2) =
400 + (2000 / 2) =
400 + 1000 =
1400
```

One of two things is happening

- [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache) is still not being picked up from `my.ini`
- [table_definition_cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache) is being picked up from `my.ini`, but is being rejected due to needed resources

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is my PC RAM is being consumed by mysqld.  Looks like the ini file is being picked up but the `table_definition_cache` is still not being set to 400.  Either way, my RAM consumption is coming down so I'm happy.